# Objective-C - sort array of strings based on string slice

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsmutablearray

NSMutableArray looks like ("xxx_20", "xxx_18", "xxx_16", "xxx_19", "xxx_17")

I want to sort it into ("xxx_16", "xxx_17", "xxx_18", "xxx_19", "xxx_20")

I've tried to use selectors, but I can't even get proper syntax. Does anyone know how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 NSMutableArray *myarray = [ NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"xxx_20", @"xxx_18", @"xxx_16", @"xxx_19", @"xxx_17", nil];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [myarray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSLog(@"%@",sortedArray);
```

It worked fine at my end.

Comment: Thanks. That did work. The selector I tried with wasn't sorting it in the order I expected. So I was trying to create my own custom selector based on a slice of just the digits and casting to ints. This is much easier.